# Handling HTTP error codes in servlet web application

Tags: servlets, web.xml, http-status-codes, custom-error-pages

I would like to know how to handle HTTP error codes in my servlet web application. How do I catch specific error codes in `web.xml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure [error-page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/web_xml.html#1017571) in web.xml one for each error-code or exception.

Sample code

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/errorPage.html</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.servlet.ServletException</exception-type>
    <location>/errorServlet</location>
</error-page>
```

Here is the [Tutorial](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/08/servlet-exception-and-error-handling-example-tutorial.html) that might help you.

Comment: is there any thing have to do in server side code?

Comment: you don't need to do anything in server side code.

Comment: For more clarity have a look at the tutorial that I shared you in my post.